# Laparoscopic surgery: Why did the gas cause pain in my shoulder, and how did it escape my body?

Tags: pain, surgery

I recently had Laparoscopic surgery, and the nurse told me I would experience pain in my shoulder and burping as the gas escapes my system. I looked up a bit of information on the "pain in my shoulder" claim, and its due to the CO2 gas irritating my phrenic nerve. So my first question is:

**Why was the pain only in my right shoulder when there is a right and left phrenic nerve?** Is it common for patients to experience pain in one or both shoulders? If CO2 causes pain/irritation, why not switch to another gas?

My second question revolves around the burping and the gas escaping my system. Basically, how? **How is it that gas in my abdominal area escapes through my mouth?** Is it through some absorption mechanism?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Does CO2 cause pain?**

CO2 can cause pain by applying **pressure** on the diaphragm; also **stretching** of the diaphragm due to the body position can irritate the phrenic nerve ([Indian Journal of Surgery](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4692943/)).

ALSO:

> It was once believed the resultant shoulder pain was simply due to
>   reaction of the gas combining with water; or that it was merely
>   trapped CO2. The actual cause of this irritation is the result of
>   **cellular death** caused by the combination of a **temperature change from the gas at 70oF and the drying effect of the gas** at
>   .0002%. Much of this irritation is centered on the diaphragmatic
>   region. Experiments with gases other than CO2 i.e. helium, nitrous
>   oxide and argon have all produced the same or similar effect [(Center
>   for Endometriosis Care)](http://centerforendo.com/post-surgical-shoulder-pain).

**Why they use CO2?**

> To begin, during Laparoscopy, CO2 (carbon dioxide) gas is injected
>   through a special needle inserted just below your navel. This is done
>   to create and maintain a distended abdomen; a condition called
>   "pneumoperitoneum."  For **safety, cost and convenience,** CO2 is used
>   almost exclusively for this purpose [(Center for Endometriosis Care)](http://centerforendo.com/post-surgical-shoulder-pain).

**Why is pain in the right shoulder?**

> The mechanism of laparoscopy-induced shoulder pain is mainly derived
>   from carbon dioxide retention within the abdomen, subsequently
>   irritating the phrenic nerve and causing referred pain in the C4
>   [dermatome](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/dermatome). Moreover, carbon dioxide trapped between the liver and the
>   **right** diaphragm, irritating the diaphragm, also causes upper abdominal pain ([JAMA Surgery](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamasurgery/fullarticle/1107256)).

BUT

> In such hiatal surgeries including LAGB and in few gynecological
>   surgeries, pain occurs preferentially on the **left** shoulder. This
>   difference suggests that the region of surgery and position of the
>   patient have an important influence on the site of pain. The cause is
>   that in laparoscopic cholecystectomy the liver is separated from the
>   undersurface of the diaphragm because of the reverse Trendelenburg
>   with a right side up position of the patient. This leads to
>   **stretching of the right hemidiaphragm** and the gas to be potentially trapped below the right diaphragm. Reverse is true for
>   hiatal surgeries ([Indian Journal of Surgery](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4692943/)).

**Where does CO2 go after surgery?**

Most of the gas passively leaves the abdominal cavity through the surgical wounds immediately after the procedure. What happens with the rest:

> Carbon dioxide readily dissolves in water and forms carbonic acid.
>   Carbonic acid is then **absorbed into the intravascular space**...([JAMA Surgery](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamasurgery/fullarticle/1107256))

CO2 is not released through the mouth and is not a direct cause of burping. Burping may result from the *pressure* of gas applied on the stomach and intestine.